# Configure Windows to treat '.' directories as hidden

Tags: windows

Many cross platform tools use the unix convention of prefixing directory names with a period to indicate they are meta directories and should not be included in file listings and directory searches. Is there a way to configure Windows so that it treats directories with a leading period as if they had the 'hidden' attribute applied?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that by normal way. Perhaps with some software...

Below, you can see an way - not the best, but to do manually for your particular case. For both cases, you must hide files with hidden attribute in Windows Explorer > Tools > View mode:

- Dos command (you can create a batch replacing each % character below with %%, and use it to initialize each time Windows is started, or when you want; use "attrib +h +s" if you want to show hidden files but hide system files; if you want to apply it for files, remove /ad parameter from dir):

  ```
  for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /s /b /ad ".*"') do attrib +h "%i"
  ```
- Windows Search (for Windows 7, you must enable classic search): search for the string ".*", then do mouse right click on directories and mark "hidden" (using this way, you cannot add system attribute)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to do this -- Windows doesn't even *let* you name files like that from within Explorer (you need the command prompt), so I don't think it would be very friendly toward treating them as hidden :(

Comment: It lets you if you know a trick. Just use .name. and you will have .name folder created. This works from Windows 7 upwards and probably in Vista,but who cares about Vista...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in general in Windows. Hidden files in Windows are determined by an attribute rather than a name convention. That's just set in stone. The best you can get is to use the [GNU tools](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), e.g. `ls` which behave the same on Windows as they do on *nix.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is hide them manually, i do this for my home folder that has alot of files and directories that begin with dot and with underscore, the last character used for VIM. Open a powershell and execute this two lines:

```
YourPSPrompt>> ls | ? {$_.name -match "^\.(.)*"} | % {attrib.exe +h $_.name}
YourPSPrompt>> ls | ? {$_.name -match "^_(.)*"} | % {attrib.exe +h $_.name}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason you can't do this at all is because in Windows, a lone period *means* "current directory". So **.\..\SiblingFolder** means exactly the same as **..\SiblingFolder**.

Comment: Yes, a single period (`.`) means "current directory" and two periods (`..`) means "parent directory" in Unix as well.  When you do a directory listing, you usually hide/ignore those "virtual" directories.  But (at least in early Unixes), they aren't actually virtual directories, but hard links, and thus ordinary filesystem entries like other files and directories.  The `ls` command hides `.` and `..` by default, but also hides any other file or directory with a name that starts with `.` (e.g. `.foo`).  Many Unix programs make use of this feature to "hide" conf files in the user home directory.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: I think it varies with OS version in Windows, but at least some MS Directory Services return **.** and **..** in scan functions. I screen them out in my code by checking for those two particular names. Maybe the corresponding Unix service does that screening for you - but lazily, by just checking if the first char is a period.